# Like button incorrectly reports zero likes for some pages

Tags: count, facebook-like

On a fairly simple website, all of the user-facing pages have the Facebook like button on them, using the iframe embed method.  Thing is, on *some* of the pages the like count is always reported as 0;  on *other* pages, the like count is reported correctly.  This is particularly odd, given that the working and non-working pages share the same page template, and therefore have the same code.

So far, I have:

- Used the FB Lint tool to confirm that the non-working pages validate correctly with no errors
- Confirmed that the og:url tag is pointing to the correct URL for the page
- Confirmed that the Like button actually works (liked content shows up on FB)
- Confirmed (via the query API) that FB actually is counting the likes, and that the likes are >0
- Confirmed that the issue seems to be page-specific;  in other words, the like button always fails on the same pages, and always works on the same pages

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Were you ever able to resolve it?